# How to query entities using backlink in ObjectBox with flutter

Tags: flutter, objectbox

This is my first time working with objectBox. I have unfortunately stumbled on this issue and I failed to solve it.
I have two entities Product and Order as below.

```
@Entity()
class Customer{
  int id;
  String name;
  @Backlink()
  final orders = ToMany<Order>();

  Customer({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.name,
  });
}

@Entity()
class Order{
  int id;
  String? orderNumber;
  final customer = ToOne<Customer>();

  Order({
    this.id = 0,
    this.orderNumber,
  });
}
```

A customer can place many orders but an order can only be placed by one customer.
I believe a list of all the orders for a specific customer can be returned simply by;

```
customer.orders;
```

But I would like to return a stream of all the orders made by a specific customer to feed into a streamBuilder. something like  Stream<List<Order>>.

I have tried to read through the objectBox docs and I see I have to do something with backlink but I have failed to make it work. I would be very greatful for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create and watch a link query, e.g. something like

```
final builder = store.box<Order>().query()
builder.link(Order_.customer, Customer.id.equals(customerId));
Stream<Query<Order>> ordersByCustomer = builder.watch();
```

Source/Details: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links